# Can I restrict access to a specific app inside a Firebase project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-analytics-firebase

I have a Firebase project that contains multiple iOS apps, each for a different customer. This is great for me to be able to view analytics across all of the apps, but I want to give each customer access to the analytics specific to their app. I see that I can create a new user and assign them the `Firebase Analytics Viewer` role which limits them to only analytics. The problem is that the user can then see analytics for all apps in the project.

Is it possible to restrict access so that a given user can only see analytics for a specific app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build comparison in google analytics [analytics.google.com](https://analytics.google.com) and provide access to specific reports to specific users. How custom reports are built and shared can be found [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1151300?hl=en).

You can build reports by specific app by using `Stream ID` filter which can help you build reports on per app basis.

[image: Dropdown showing Stream ID as an available filter to build comparison]

Answer (score 0):

finally you can do the same with firebase, but the question was how to give access to the firebase itself with particular permission.
It's a workaround to share the report.
Imagine each time that a change occurs you need to resend the report.
We are looking for particular permission for the user to access only the event and the user property for a particular app.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35339025)